# Inverse function on matrices with help of Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series, matrix-calculus, inverse-problems, cayley-hamilton

I have been thinking about inverse functions of matrices lately.

(Yees yees, I know usually for anything more complicated than reals we need to define/select branch and for reals to select interval of validity.)

One of the things I got to think about is the results using Caley-Hamilton theorem $$P_1(A) = 0$$ to show how to calculate $P_2,P_3$ such that: $$A^{n} = P_2(A)$$ and $$A^{-1}=P_3(A)$$ somehow in combination with power series expansion representation.

1. Is this theoretically correct?
2. Is this practically useful in cases we want to solve $$f(A)=B$$

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of your second sentence in parentheses. Taking the inverse of an invertible matrix is a perfectly well-defined operation. You don't need to select branch cuts to define the inverse of an invertible complex number either. You would need to be more careful if you wanted to take logarithms of matrices.

Comment: I am not just talking of matrices, but functions of matrices. $f$ is not always a simple function. For example try to invert $A\to A^2$ already for reals $A\in \mathbb R^{1\times 1}$ you don't have enough information you need to choose solution in positive or negative reals.

Comment: Most of your question seems to be about how to compute the inverse of a matrix. Now it sounds like you want to compute the inverse of a function defined on matrices. That's a very different question; which is it?

Comment: The function value of a matrix input will be a matrix so it relates to both matrix inversion and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a $k\times k$ matrix.

The Cayley-Hamilton theorem has the consequence that, for every $n$, there exists a polynomial of degree at most $k-1$, $P_n(x)=a_{0,n}+a_{1,n}x+\dots+a_{k-1,n}x^{k-1}$, such that
$$
A^n=P_n(A)
$$
(only nonnegative $n$ if $A$ is not invertible).

Indeed, $P_n=x^n$ for $0\le n\le k-1$; if $k=n$ we can consider the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)=c_0+c_1x+\dots+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+x^k$ and write
$$
A^k=-c_0I-c_1A-\dots-c_{k-1}A^{k-1}
$$
and do induction on $n$ for $n>k$.

If $A$ is invertible, we know that $c_0\ne0$, so from
$$
c_0A^{-1}=-c_1A-\dots-c_{k-1}A^{k-2}-A^{k-1}
$$
we obtain $A^{-1}=P_{-1}(A)$ with obvious steps. Then we can do induction again.

The induction proof will also provide recursive formulas for the coefficients $a_{i,n}$.